# How to make row layout ignore previous row

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a row, whose last `td` element needs to take up 50% of the row's width:

[Take a look at column 3.](http://jsfiddle.net/741q8nnc/1/)

However, I also need the `td` in the first row to fill up entire row. When I set its width to 100%, it affects the second row:

[Now look what happened!](http://jsfiddle.net/741q8nnc/)

Is there a way to make the second row ignore the column size of the previous row(s)?
The only alternative I can think of is using a single `td` in 2nd row, and doing the division inside it (which might work in my simplified example, but in real life would be an absolute mess).

Browser: Google Chrome.

NOTE: Unfortunately, using divs instead of tables isn't an option :(

Comment: If it's a `table`, when you change one of the `td` width, it will reflect in the whole column. What were you expecting?

Comment: Have you heard about `colspan`? http://jsfiddle.net/741q8nnc/2/

Comment: @MelanciaUK, the same works if I give width in px; so why not %?

Comment: Are you sure it works? http://jsfiddle.net/741q8nnc/3/

Comment: @MelanciaUK Well, I'll be... It worked on MY machine. :S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to apply `colspan` to the cell that is to span the full width of the table. In this case as there are 3 cells in the second row you would need to add `colspan="3"`.

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td class="wide">3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/pak1hx68/